# Python; read and write all files in a folder

Tags: python, glob

I want to write a code in Python which should read all the files in a folder and then convert them to Wav format.
I am using below code, but it get no result:

```py
import glob
import obspy
from obspy import read

directory = '/home/data/*'

files = glob.glob(directory)

for file in files:
    f = obspy.read ('file')
    f.write (str(f.name)+ '.wav', format='wav')
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `f = obspy.read ('file')` results in an attempt to read the file named "file". Please mind the difference between the variable `file` and the string literal "file". It would be good to print various things during the execution. This way you would know what is going on. Try adding `print(f.name)` after reading the file.

BTW. Are you sure f object has a property `name`? I don't see it in the documentation for [obspy Stream](https://docs.obspy.org/packages/autogen/obspy.core.stream.Stream.html#obspy.core.stream.Stream) returned by `obspy.read()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. yes I changed the ('file') to (file). And for the name, I think you are right. But the problem is not this. When I change the the last line to f.write ( 'new.wav', format='wav'), still it does not do any thing.

Comment: If you get no errors, no output at all, then most probably there are no files matching the pattern `'/home/data/*'`. Again, the simplest way to find out what's is going on is to print some information. For example `print(len(files), 'files found')` after `glob()` call. `print('processing file', file)` at the beginning of the for loop.

Comment: Thanks. Now I wrote but the problem is in the loop for. It just write the last file.  for file in folder:
    st = obspy.read (file)
    fn= open (file)
    #st.write ( str(fn.name)+'.wav', format='wav')

Comment: The code I wrote above just works for the last file in the folder.

Comment: The only thing that I can come up with, is that you might have some indentation issue and the output is written to file after the loop (not indented to be inside the loop).

Comment: I just made it with a small change! Thank you